# AngularJS + Provider + Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, this

Имеется angularjs-приложение, которое при сборке "накрывается" *webpack'ом* (при сборке используется так же **babel-loader**).

Собственно говоря, есть файл **MessageProvider.js** со следующим кодом:

```
const SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER = ['$injector', ($injector) => {

var localeJson = [];

this.loadLocale = (lang) => {
    ....
};

this.$get = () => {
    return {
        ....
    };
};
}];
export { SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER };
```

После успешной сборки приложения **с помощью webpack'a**, в браузере отображается ошибка:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module *название приложения* due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'loadLocale' of undefined
```

Указывая на строку

```
this.loadLocale = (lang) => ....
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение проблемы. Оказалось, "*стрелочные*" функции нельзя использовать в качестве конструкторов (поэтому у них нет `this.`).

Достаточно просто изменить:

```
const SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER = ['$injector', ($injector) => {
```

на:

```
const SERVER_SIDE_MESSAGE_PROVIDER = ['$injector', function($injector) {
```